# Correlation between several variables in different study areas

Tags: correlation, ecology

I want to test the correlation between variables considering several study areas. I aim to study habitat selection using telemetry data (locations) in five study areas, and I have variables regarding landcover (10; in % for each study area), topography (1) and distance to water/human settlements (2; mean for each study area). In total, I have 13 variables Before starting with habitat selection analyses, I want to check if the variables I am using are correlated, in order to perform analyses using only independent variables. I am not sure how to analyse this with several study areas.

What is the best way to perform the analysis?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, the variables, & your goals here? This is rather sparse & abstract at the moment.

Comment: I just updated the post, if any more information is necessary please let me know!

Comment: So you will have a dataset with 5 rows (for the values from each location), & 1 column for each variable, is that right? How many variables are there, 3?

Comment: Yes, 5 rows (one for each study area), and 10 variables regarding land cover, one related with topography and the two distances (to water and to human settlements); so 13 variables in total. Within each study area I have several animals with several locations, but I don't think that should be important for the correlation between the variables, or should it?

Comment: Update your question with the numbers of variables. You have a matrix of [5×13] and you want to find the correlation between these 13 variables based on the 5 observations? There are too few data to do such a work. If you obtain more data, this question has been asked and answered several times in Stackexchange. There are techniques like: principal component analysis, pearson correlation, ...

Comment: @PeyM87, +1 I meant to make those points but got pulled away. that is the answer, why not make it an official one? (Then this won't count as officially unanswered.)

Comment: Updated! Well, my problem is, I don't know at which level I should test the correlation: if it is among study areas, among individuals (within each area) or among relocations (within individuals)? What do you think? Please bear in mind that I don't have the same number of individuals between study areas nor the same number of relocations; my dataset is very heterogeneous!

Comment: It depends on your scientific question. Can you in fact correlate at the individual animal level? Will not things like land cover be constant for animals within study area?

Comment: That's what I want to test by appyling, for example, resource selection functions. But yes, I think some variables will be constant. That's why I thought to test the correlation considering only the five areas, but that may not be correct since those areas alone represent a small sample size.

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques known in "parameter selection" section part of a work. After parameter selection comes modelling.

In parameter selection you analyze relations between parameters and rank the parameters in order of importance. Here are some of the works:

1. A Regression model and observe the p-values of the coefficients of each variable
2. Pearson Correlation
3. Spearman Correlation
4. Kendall Correlation
5. Mutual Information
6. RReliefF algorithm
7. Decision trees
8. Principal Component Analysis, etc.

Note that you need enough amount of data for your results to be accurate.

After you have performed these variable importance analyses, you can rank the variables and then compare the ranks and thus the case studies.